# Laravel 5.1 grouped route with resource controller not working

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-5

I have a grouped route in Laravel 5.1 in order to place 'announcement' below 'admin'. When i access http://app.local/announcement everything works and i get 'hello'. However, when i access http://app.local/admin/announcement I get nothing. No error - just a blank screen.

Any ideas??

Routes.php:

```
//Admin controller.
Route::resource('admin', 'AdminController');
//Route for admin/announcement
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin'], function () {
    Route::resource('announcement', 'AnnouncementController');
});
//Test route.
Route::resource('announcement', 'AnnouncementController');
```

My announcement controller:

```
class AnnouncementController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return dd('hello');
    }
}
```

PHP artisan route:list (relevant section):

```
|        | GET|HEAD                       | admin/announcement                                   | admin.announcement.index   | App\Http\Controllers\AnnouncementController@index                         |                         |
|        | POST                           | admin/announcement                                   | admin.announcement.store   | App\Http\Controllers\AnnouncementController@store                         |                         |
|        | GET|HEAD                       | admin/announcement/create                            | admin.announcement.create  | App\Http\Controllers\AnnouncementController@create                        |                         |
|        | PATCH                          | admin/announcement/{announcement}                    |                            | App\Http\Controllers\AnnouncementController@update                        |                         |
|        | DELETE                         | admin/announcement/{announcement}                    | admin.announcement.destroy | App\Http\Controllers\AnnouncementController@destroy                       |                         |
|        | PUT                            | admin/announcement/{announcement}                    | admin.announcement.update  | App\Http\Controllers\AnnouncementController@update                        |                         |
|        | GET|HEAD                       | admin/announcement/{announcement}                    | admin.announcement.show    | App\Http\Controllers\AnnouncementController@show                          |                         |
|        | GET|HEAD                       | admin/announcement/{announcement}/edit               | admin.announcement.edit    | App\Http\Controllers\AnnouncementController@edit                          |                         |
|        | GET|HEAD                       | announcement                                         | announcement.index         | App\Http\Controllers\AnnouncementController@index                         |                         |
|        | POST                           | announcement                                         | announcement.store         | App\Http\Controllers\AnnouncementController@store                         |                         |
|        | GET|HEAD                       | announcement/create                                  | announcement.create        | App\Http\Controllers\AnnouncementController@create                        |                         |
|        | PATCH                          | announcement/{announcement}                          |                            | App\Http\Controllers\AnnouncementController@update                        |                         |
|        | DELETE                         | announcement/{announcement}                          | announcement.destroy       | App\Http\Controllers\AnnouncementController@destroy                       |                         |
|        | GET|HEAD                       | announcement/{announcement}                          | announcement.show          | App\Http\Controllers\AnnouncementController@show                          |                         |
|        | PUT                            | announcement/{announcement}                          | announcement.update        | App\Http\Controllers\AnnouncementController@update                        |                         |
|        | GET|HEAD                       | announcement/{announcement}/edit                     | announcement.edit          | App\Http\Controllers\AnnouncementController@edit                          |                         |
```

Many thanks,
Steve

Comment: A blank screen is an error. If your application could not find an applicable route, it throws an error. If your application is never used, apache throws a 404. Somewhere, there is an error, and you sir, you need to find it.

Comment: Thanks for that Mikel - i can't argue. There is indeed an error - just wish the output was a little more verbose! I feel i've broken it down as much as i can. I'm wondering if resource controllers are not supported within route groups?

Comment: They are- I'm using them in my routes. Did you turn on APP_DEBUG in your environment? Is display_errors on?

Comment: Issue found: i had a route to 'admin' just before the route group. So it was interfering with the 'admin' group that was after it. Argh... I've edited the code above to show what i did wrong - might help someone else.

Comment: Good find! Sometimes the complexity of web boggles my mind.

Comment: @SteveGoddard consider leaving the wrong code and adding a "Update" section in your question where you quickly explain what was wrong and how to fix it.